# Problems with Phototobucket oAuth

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth, photobucket

Seems like a lot of people have problems getting oAuth to work with Photobucket and now I'm one of them, I keep getting:

```
"Authentication failed signature check failed"
```

When trying to get a request token, here is the header info I send along:

```
OAuth realm=""
oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXX"
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"
oauth_signature="BHHJ4o7zXOlfln4Xpik5rPtjZv8%3D"
oauth_timestamp="1323470655"
oauth_nonce="2FEC3150-8AB9-4BBC-BC4B-FA5AE7EC8046"
oauth_version="1.0"
```

and my BASE string used to generate the signature:

```
POST&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.photobucket.com%2Flogin%2Frequest&format%3Djson%26oauth_consumer_key%3DXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_nonce%3D2FEC3150-8AB9-4BBC-BC4B-FA5AE7EC8046%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1323470655%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

Everything seems on the up and up and I'm using the same library that I've been using for several other photo/video sharing sites with no problems, this is on iOS...

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't there be an oauth_token in there as well?

Comment: Not when I'm trying to get the request token, this is the start of authentication.  Get request token -> ask user to authorize -> exchange request token for access token.

Comment: so it getting failed for getting request token?

Comment: Can't really see anything wrong with your base string nor headers... You made sure that your signature key is `"CONSUMER_SECRET" + "&"` and not just `"CONSUMER_SECRET"`?

Comment: @JonNylander You mean when I'm signing the basestring?  Yea, its CONSUMER_SECRET&  I also can't see anything wrong here and its not my 1st time to the rodeo which is frustrating :p

Comment: I know the feeling. Next classic question: are you sure you are actually sending the request token request as POST?

Comment: Yup, I'm watching the traffic with HTTPScoop sniffer to make sure the request and responses are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that even though photobucket causes your requests to sometimes go to api####.photobucket.com (your special load balancing URL) you still have to specify your base string as api.photobucket.com which makes no sense and **TOTALLY BREAKS** oAuth since you're now setting your base string to a different url than where you're making the request :p

So, be vigilant and always make sure your base string is api.photobucket.com

*sigh*